# Reading file using python is not working properly in Linux

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, windows-10, python-3.7, codec

I'm running a python code where we read a fixed width file, which we extracted from ftp server. the code is working on windows without any issue. but when i am running the same code in the linux ec2 instance it's giving an error saying that "**UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x99 in position 1819: invalid start byte**". but the same code running in windows without any error.since i am not aware about the encoding type of the source file i am passing the encoding type as None. And this also working fine in windows but when we running the code in linux its giving an error saying that "**encoding type None is not recognize**".
i am using the codecs library to read the file and python version that i am using is 3.7.3

```
with codecs.open("recode.dat",encoding=None,errors='replace') as open_src:
    with open("target_file.dat", 'w+',encoding=None) as open_tgt:
        for src_rec in open_src:
            new_rec = ''
            for f_length in data_type_length:
                f_length = int(f_length)
                field = '"' + src_rec[:f_length].strip() + '"|'
                new_rec += (field)
                src_rec = src_rec[f_length:]


            open_tgt.write(new_rec[:-1] + '\n')
```

Comment: ASCII has all bytes less than 0x80. Anything else is encoded.

Comment: @stark only the data inside the file and i am not sure the encode type of that. That's why i am passing the encoding type as None. i want to get the file as it is.

Comment: A codec converts from the external form to a python unicode string. The default is utf-8. Windows may be using something like cp1252 depending on the locale where the data was written. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html for a description of built-in codecs.

Comment: @stark Thank you very much. but in above answer you mention about ASCII has all bytes less than 0x80. what do you mean by that. can you explain little bit more

Comment: Most Western encodings use the ASCII character set for values in the range 0x20 to 0x7e.  These are the printable ASCII characters found in "plain text" files.  If a file contains values outside that range, it is not plain text and must be decoded by the same codec that was used to create it.  Otherwise bytes will map to the wrong characters.  0x99 maps to the "trademark" symbol in CP1252.